# SQLITE Multiple Table Join With Nested Select Issues Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, left-join

I'm currently rewriting an AS3/AIR based app for Android/Java which I'm not super familiar with.
Previously in AS3 I had some quite complicated SELECT statements involving left outer joins which I'm having trouble getting to work with Androids way of things.

The query below is one of the simpler ones I'm dealing with. I have attempted to do it first up using a rawQuery as follows:

```
String myQuery = "SELECT *FROM  category CA
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
             (SELECT E.CategoryFK,  IFNULL(SUM(E.Amount),0) AS AmountSummed
                      FROM expense E WHERE date(julianday(E.ExpDate))
                      BETWEEN date('now', 'localtime','start of month')  AND date('now', 'localtime')
                      GROUP BY E.CategoryFK)E ON CA.Key = E.CategoryFK
            GROUP BY  Name ORDER BY Key";

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
```

When I'm testing this I get back the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported (code 1):
```

I'm a bit of an SQLITE noob as well but as far as I can see there are no RIGHT or FULL outers joins here.

I also know that doing this as a rawQuery is apparently not the way to go, and instead I should be looking at using the query function.

My question is how is a complex join with conditionals supposed to be put into a parametized query statement if the rawQuery like this gives issues?

I can't find any examples of people doing really complex multi-table join SELECT queries using Android/Java...

Should I be using the SQLiteQueryBuilder features to do something like this?

Thanks for any help.

Cheers
Marco

Comment: Your code looks correct. Which Android version are you using?

Comment: Hi CL I'm testing using Genymotion Nexus 5 emulator running API 19. I guess I'm wondering if this raw string doesn't work how I would actually deconstruct it and plug it into use either the SQLiteQueryBuilder class or use the "normal" db.query() method with parameters... Marco

Comment: Using `rawQuery` is OK; other functions would not help. If this is the actual code you're using, it looks like a bug in this particular version of SQLite. Try just `LEFT JOIN`, but I have the feeling that `myQuery` is not what ends up at the database.

Comment: Hi CL Thanks for your feebback. I worked out there was a String concatenation problem which was causing errors on the line breaks for this statement in the actual code. So I got this statement working ok as a rawQuery. Thanks. Marco